# ViewPager work not correctly

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager

Can not implement so: if tap to image in MainActivity - this image has to open in PreviewActivity full screen and there I can make scroll right and left use ViewPager to browse the next or previous image in the array. Now, when i tap to image, and if use in `PageFragment` - `resultView.setImageResource(pageNumber);` - then always open firts image in my array, and if use `resultView.setImageURI(source);` - then open true image but if swipe - always show this one image.
**PageFragment** - probably in this class something wrong

```
public class PageFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String ARGUMENT_PAGE_NUMBER = "id_test";
    private int pageNumber;
    private Uri source;

    static PageFragment newInstance(int page) {
        PageFragment pageFragment = new PageFragment();
        Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
        arguments.putInt(ARGUMENT_PAGE_NUMBER, page);
        pageFragment.setArguments(arguments);
        return pageFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Intent i = getActivity().getIntent();
        pageNumber = i.getExtras().getInt("id_test");
        source = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.test.nico/drawable/" + Images.loadImages[pageNumber]);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_view_pager, null);

        ImageView resultView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.result_image);
//        resultView.setImageURI(source);
        pageNumber = getArguments().getInt(ARGUMENT_PAGE_NUMBER);
        resultView.setImageResource(pageNumber);
        return view;
    }
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Context mContext;
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private ImageAdapter mImageAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mContext = getApplicationContext();
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        mImageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(mContext, Images.loadImages);
        mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2);

        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mImageAdapter);
    }
}
```

**PreviewActivity**

```
public class PreviewActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private PagerAdapter pagerAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_preview);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.preview_pager);
        pagerAdapter = new PreviewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
    }
}
```

**ImageAdapter**

```
class ImageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ImageAdapter.Holder> {
    private int[] mItemList;
    private Context mContext;

    ImageAdapter(Context context, int[] itemList) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mItemList = itemList;
    }

    @Override
    public Holder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View layoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.view_list, null);
        return new Holder(layoutView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(Holder holder, int position) {
        Picasso.with(mContext).load(Images.loadImages[position]).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_stub).resize(400, 750).into(holder.view);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return this.mItemList.length;
    }

    class Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        ImageView view;

        Holder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mContext = itemView.getContext();
            view = new ImageView(mContext);
            view = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            final Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, PreviewActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("id_test", getAdapterPosition());
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

**PreviewPagerAdapter**

```
class PreviewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private int imagesCount = Images.loadImages.length;
    private int[] images = Images.loadImages;

    PreviewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return imagesCount;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return PageFragment.newInstance(images[position]);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }
}
```

Comment: "cool" webservice, Instead of helping easier votedown...

Comment: Do not use ViewPager, consider to use RecyclerView instead

Comment: @ Stepango thanks! good idea i will try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `PreviewActivity` you have to "jump" to the position you passed.

```
viewpager.setCurrentItem(getIntent().getExtras().getInt("id_test"));
```